# MapBox annotation title centering in Swift

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm using `MGLPointAnnotation` to show pin on the map in Swift. I set a title and a subtitle as follow:

```
    annotation.title = "Last position"
    annotation.subtitle = "2020/05/19-15:19:27"
```

It looks good:

[image]

But I'd like to center the text to look like this:

[image]

Is it doable with native `MGLPointAnnotation` or do I have to build a custom one ?

Answer (score 0):

Aligning the title and subtitle of an MGLPointAnnotation is not possible without the use of a custom callout view. Please take a look at the [display custom views as callouts example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/custom-callout/), which uses a custom view to customize the appearance of your callout text.